# Read properties from springboot application.yml into java class

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following yaml structure in my application.yml file

```
persons:
  - name: john
    age: 24
    height: 1.34
  - name: james
    age: 27
    height: 1.52
```

and this java class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class PlayerDetails{

    private List<String> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getAllPeopleDetails() {
      System.out.println("People Details: \n");

      for (String person: persons) {
        System.out.println(person);
      }
   }
 }
```

However, the persons list is null. I don't know what I might be doing wrongly. Kindly assist in pointing me to the right way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to your configuration class?

Comment: Also remove `person` variable initzialiation, spring will do it.

Comment: I have done as you recommended but result is still same.

Answer (score 1):

Remake your PlayerDetails like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class PlayerDetails{

    private List<PlayerDetail> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class PlayerDetail {
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String height;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(String height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    public String getAllPeopleDetails() {
        System.out.println("People Details: \n");

        for (PersonDetail person: persons) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for rearranging the code, but it didn't make any difference. The output is same

Comment: I have this code and it is working. Try to add @EnableConfigurationProperties  and also be sure that this class is involved in component scan with your application. Is this bean being initialized?

Comment: yes the class is involved in component scan and the bean is being initialized as well. I added @EnableConfigurationProperties as you recommended, still getting an empty list

Comment: everything sounds right, so i have no idea, why it doesn't work. Try to find typos, check logs and also check if indendation is ok in yaml, and that nothing is before persons in yaml

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I changed my approach, hence I no longer need this approach. However, any one with useful info as to how this can be resolved is welcome because it might help someone in future.